# How can I create an android menu item using android setting icon

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I create an android menu item using android setting icon?

Comment: What is "android setting icon"?

Comment: I'm sure he is referring to gear icons like [these](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gear+setting+icon&oq=gear+setting+icon&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2972j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is a [list of the standard icons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#menuapx).  I don't see a "settings" icon.  Perhaps you mean "Preferences" (`ic_menu_preferences`)?

You can set the icon programmatically like this:

```
menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_quit_icon);
```

You can also set it in your xml layout like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/save_button"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
      android:title="Save Image"/>
```

- [Creating Menus in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: +1 thanks, I was looking for how to reference the drawable from xml.

Comment: The code xml, not work correctly in Material Design (2015) and java, the line is created of other form "getMenuInflater(),.."

Comment: Must be missing something. Not material design, did the above, and I see no settings icon. Shows up in Android studio in the code, but not on the screen!

Comment: For me referring to a private icon works without `android` prefix e.g. `android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"`. It worked even when I had not copied the image in my project. I'm wondering how it is possible to refer images of Android SDK without `android` prefix which you've mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 9):

You can see all the icons in the android SDK forder:

```
_your_install_path_\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable-hdpi\
```

and then get a reference to them with:

```
android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences
```

just like it was your drawable.

Comment: Worth mentioning: some of them aren't public, thus unusable.

Answer (score 7):

#### Add a new Vector Asset.

1. File -> New -> Vector Asset.

[image]

2. Click on the icon to change it.

[image]

3. Select the icon you want (e.g. search for "setting").

[image]

4. Adjust other settings.
5. Use that new Vector Asset in your xml.

   ```
   android:logo="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
   ```
6. Party!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the event, just try this on your activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case android.R.drawable.ic_popup_sync:
                Toast.makeText(this, "ic_popup_sync selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And in your menu folder use something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.test.app.MainActivity"
    >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:title="Find Location"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:title="Save Image"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
        android:title="Refresh"/>


</menu>
```