# Android: anyone know the filename for the "settings" icon?

Tags: android

I am looking for the gear shaped settings icon but can't find it in the sdk drawables. Does anyone know the filename?

Thank you

Comment: I created a new Vector Asset for our Settings icon. You can find the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58347649/293280

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe that `ic_menu_preferences.png` is what you're looking for. It's in the `drawables-?dpi` directories, not in `drawables`.

Answer (score 12):

This is a handy page I found for the built in icons:

http://since2006.com/android/2.1-drawables.php

Comment: Be aware that the images at that URL are wrong for the 9-patch images. They were taken from compiled resources and do not have the correct borders. It's much better to retrieve the images from the SDK directories (or from the [online source repository](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res) directly).

Comment: Images in the link are broken now.

Answer (score 10):

`ic_setting_dark` as described in Honest Objections's answer seems to be gone (or deprecated). At least I was not able to find it in API 24. However, the method and the containing link are still valid, i.e.:

`"@android:drawable/<drawable>"` where `<drawable>` is one of the ids listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html), e.g. `ic_menu_preferences` (which, unfortunately, is not a gear but a wrench ...)

---

In the meantime, google released a huge set of material icons at [material.io](https://material.io/icons/) which can be directly used in Android Studio to create svg or png assets as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html). tl;dr:

> In the Android view of the Project window, right-click the res folder and select **New > Vector Asset**.

Answer (score 3):

Just for anyone visiting this in the future, it can be found directly under drawable if you have the SDK, along with many [others](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html):

`android:src="@drawable/ic_setting_dark"`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the nice **cog icon** in Android Asset Studio by searching for the `settings` icon.

You can open Android Asset Studio by right-clicking `res: drawable` and selecting `New: Image Asset`.