# PopupMenu Android DelphiXE5 what is the bestway to do

Tags: android, popupmenu, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to create this like this form.

This is a TPopupMenu or a TPanel or a TForm? I try with panel and it works, but i dont know if exist's anyway simpliest to do this.

Anyone know's the right way to do this?

[image]

similar questions was posted here [PopupMenu with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons) but isn't DelphiXE5

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this article:
[Creating an Overflow Menu on Android](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2013/10/17/463/), it is a TListBox what is used but i think it is what you are looking for.