# Android menu item with both icon and text together when showAsAction is never

Tags: android, xml, menu, icons

[image: Menu items with title and icon when showAsAction is never]

Hi, how can I make my menu items have icons as well when showAsAction is never ?

Comment: Why you make showAsAction equals never? If you want to show menu item with icons, value of showAsAction must be withText.`android:showAsAction = "withText"`

Comment: Because, that is the way I want them to appear. I do not want the menu item to appear in ActionBar but inside menu. When showAsAction is never, only text is displayed, but I want icon to appear as well, like the ones in picture.

Comment: There are some work around.
I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons) will help you.

Comment: @Harry Mad  I tried submenus. But it still didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `android:actionLayout` in menu item tag to specify custom lyout (icon with text). 
Menu item will look like:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit_menu"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_edit_row"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/edit"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
```

Edit

```
custom_edit_row.xml
```

will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/edit_ic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Edit" />
```

Comment: Thanks Saad, i got your point. But can you please, show me an example layout of "custom_edit_row" ?

Comment: @Elnoor please see the changes

Comment: For me, `app:actionLayout` worked, instead of `android:actionLayout`.

Comment: how do you handle clicks on this menu item?

Answer (score 1):

Use this menu file, it worked fine for me.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_m"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="menu">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_one"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
                android:showAsAction="always"
                android:title="Sync"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_two"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
                android:title="About"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Harry Mad, but the thing is that it is a submenu. But what I want is to display icon main menu item

Answer (score 1):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".YourActivityName">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled"
            android:title="PROFILE"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>

</item>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just change root item of Harry Mad answer

```
    <item
    android:title="Ещё"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert">
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

In createOptionsMenu, set the icon and text to MenuItem.

Elaborate the problem a little more.