# Android drop-down options menu with icons

Tags: android

How to make drop-down menus with icons like Telegram app:

[image: Telegram options menu]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android menu item with both icon and text together when showAsAction is never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777318/android-menu-item-with-both-icon-and-text-together-when-showasaction-is-never)

Answer (score 0):

Use in your menu xml file "icon":

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_call"
        android:title="@string/call" />
```