# Why are my icons displaying empty circles in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a navigation menu with icons and links, but for some reason my icons are not showing. [image]

Here is where I added the images in the menu/menu resource file. For some reason the images all appear as circles as seen in the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="Search" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_sell"
        android:icon="@drawable/sell"
        android:title="Sell" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_wishlist"
        android:icon="@drawable/bookmark"
        android:title="Wishlist" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_listings"
        android:icon="@drawable/list"
        android:title="Listings" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/person"
        android:title="Logout" />

</group>
```

Comment: I believe it's due to `android:checkableBehavior="single"`. It makes the items behave as radio buttons, that's why they appear as circles.

Comment: Also.. doesn't your file contain a `<menu>` tag? If it doesn't, I think you definitely should change `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` into `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`.

Comment: HI there. I tried changing it to menu but I am still getting the same problem... Is there maybe something else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33777318/2679327