# PopMenus with icons

Tags: android, android-layout, contextmenu, layout-inflater

I want to achieve exactly like [PopupMenu with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons/15455081?noredirect=1#comment62408802_15455081)  On layout click which is in Custom Toolbar . So , i have taken the help of an answer but issue i am facing is : Nothing is poping out on click .

**POPLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/poplayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/backgroud_user" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cloud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CHECKIN"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/backgroud_user" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Toolbar.xml(consist of an layout to be clicked)**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:text="My Assignments"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

            <LinearLayout(**layout to be clicked**)
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#75aadb"
                android:id="@+id/accountinfo_layout"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/account"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Code.class**

```
accountInfoLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               if(point!=null){
                    int[] location = new int[2];
                    v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                    point = new Point();
                    point.x = location[0];
                    point.y = location[1];
                    showPopup(getActivity(),point);
                }
```

// The method that displays the popup.

```
  private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
            int popupWidth = 200;
            int popupHeight = 150;

            // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
            LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.poplayout);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_window, viewGroup);

            // Creating the PopupWindow
            final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
            popup.setContentView(layout);
            popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
            popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
            popup.setFocusable(true);

            // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
            int OFFSET_X = 30;
            int OFFSET_Y = 30;

            // Clear the default translucent background
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

            // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
            popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

        }
```

> Nothing in showing on click . Please help me in finding Bug .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just remove  if(point!=null) condition it will work

```
accountInfoLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    int[] location = new int[2];
                    v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                    point = new Point();
                    point.x = location[0];
                    point.y = location[1];
                    showPopup(getActivity(),point);
                }
}
}
```