# Dialog Open on Recycler view Row button click

Tags: android

In Recycler View I click on a button add to cart a dialog is open.
In Recycler view adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.addtocart.setOnClickListener((Mp3HindiLandingActivity) context);
}
```

In My Activity(Mp3HindiLandingActivity)

```
          @Override
         public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) { case R.id.addtocart:
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, v);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu1:

                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "FriendRequest", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.menu2:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Block | Hide ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();

            break;`
           }}
```

It Shows the the menu below addtocart icon but I need the menu items having different background as per the image attached?

Please let me know how this will be implemented
[image: Please Refer Image]

Comment: Give us your soucecode and we can find a solution. But just posting a problem and assuming, that anyone will code for you is not the way we will do it here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this.

```
paletteViewHolder.btncart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(paletteViewHolder.imgpopup.getContext(), v);
                    // This activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener .
                    //popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener ((OnMenuItemClickListener) this);
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.friendrequest:
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "FriendRequest", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.blockhide:
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Block | Hide ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.followunfollow:
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Follow/UnFollow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return true;
                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                            //return false;
                        }
                    });
                    popup.inflate(R.menu.menu);
                    popup.show();
                }
            });
```

//create below menu.xml file on menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:title="menu1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:title="menu2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:title="menu3"/>
</menu>
```

its helpfull for you.

Comment: @Atul Mavani can i set image in Popup menu

Comment: thank you for your answer.. it working good.. and i succeed on set image in popup menu.. +1 for you.

Comment: @Atul Mavani  How can we customize the design of the popup menu as per the image attached?.

Answer (score 2):

First create an inner class ViewHolder likes below:

```
private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public Button btnCart;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        btnCart = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCart);
    }
}
```

Then override onBindViewHolder in your adapter (your adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter).

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // call the opening of your dialog here
           }
        });

    }
```

Comment: i m implementing the same thing here .. i know  how to make click event,, what i want to know is how to make that custom dialog with image. like in image shown above..

Comment: Dang Nguyen I tried it but dialog is shown top of the screen, but according to functionality the dialog should be below of cart icon. It should be for each and every row

Comment: Create a popup menu as @Atul Mavani's help will work. You can get more details about how to make popup menu with icons here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons