# Support v7 MenuPopupHelper is now hidden and restricted to LIBRARY_GROUP

Tags: android, android-appcompat, lint

Recently i've been getting a lint error on my usage of `android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper` which is now hidden and restricted to be only used within its library group.

**Exact message:**

`MenuPopupHelper constructor can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)`

**Excerpt from the `MenuPopupHelper.java` class:**

```
/**
 * Presents a menu as a small, simple popup anchored to another view.
 *
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)
public class MenuPopupHelper implements MenuHelper {
```

**Question:**
Any idea when and why this happened ? or whats the workaround that I should look for ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130193) that this is a bug in the pre-release version of the tool.

If you want a project wide workaround, put the snippet below in the `build.gradle` file of your project

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    disable 'RestrictedApi'
  }
}
```

OR
use the annotation below to suppress the lint warning for that particular method or class

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
```

Comment: Can you please add some information/link supporting `I just found out this is a bug in the pre-release version of the tool.`

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in Lint report:

> Error: MenuPopupHelper.show can only be called from within  the same
> library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.appcompat with
> prefix androidx from groupId=MyProject) [RestrictedApi]
> }.show()

If you don't use [icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons) in `PopupMenu`, you can remove `MenuPopupHelper`:

Before:

```
val popupMenu = PopupMenu(context, v)
...
val menuHelper = MenuPopupHelper(context, popupMenu.menu as MenuBuilder, v)
menuHelper.gravity = Gravity.END
menuHelper.show()
```

After:

```
val popupMenu = PopupMenu(context, v)
...
popupMenu.gravity = Gravity.END
popupMenu.show()
```

Or add `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I migrated to AndroidX and I replaced the following classes:
`android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`
`android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper`
with the new ones:
`androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu`
`androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper`
and I obtained the same lint error.
After looking to the reference docs, I discovered that now I can obtain the same behavior using just **PopupMenu**, without the need of **MenuPopupHelper**, even if my popup menu has icons.

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.opzioni_programma, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_programma_calendar:
                            // menu item logic
                        case R.id.action_programma_search:
                            // menu item logic
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.setForceShowIcon(true);
            popup.show();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu` instead:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
popup.inflate(R.menu.mymenu);
//or
//popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, popup.getMenu());
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        final int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.someid:
                //do something
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
popup.show();
```

Comment: AFAIK PopMenu doesn't allow you to add icons to menu rows, which is why we switched to `MenuPopupHelper` in the first place.